# Encoding method that produces string starting with #_1_

Tags: encoding

I'm trying to write a script to convert configurations between two routers - export config from one router, import valid settings into second router. Some of the strings (e.g. VPN certs) get Base64 encoded, which I've got working. (Note enCODED, not enCRYPTED - no key required to decode.) However, one of the Keys get encrypted with a different algorithm. Every output from the algorithm starts with `#_1_` and ends with `=`, but I can't find an algorithms that produce that output.

I've pushed some simple strings into one of the encoded fields to check that `#_1_` is a header and not by chance:

`String      ASCII                               Encoded
abcABC      [97][98][99][65][66][67]            #_1_BXadLg7VzqM=

123456      [49][50][51][52][53][54]            #_1_VSbNW3mg5DI=

00000000    [48][48][48][48][48][48][48][48]    #_1_VCTOX3ymd3Yt8w==`

Can anyone point me towards a hint on how to encode strings to this method?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It might be encrypted with AES. The "#_1_" part is probably an arbitrary header, and AES results often end with one or two `=` characters because of padding.

Comment: Doug - correct. The manufacturer has finally replied, they accept an encoded input, but then encrypt it. When you export the config, it is encrypted. They can accept encoded or encrypted input.

Answer (score 0):

The device manufacturer has indicated that these fields are encrypted. They can accept either encoded or encrypted input, but encrypt it for storage or export.